# Load an embed control from ajax results with PDF

Tags: jquery, html, embed

I have a DIV with an ID of "award"   inside that DIV, I have an EMBED...

```
<div id="award">
  <embed src="" width="400" height="500">
</div>
```

In my click bind, i am calling an AJAX control

```
  $.ajax({
url: "handlers/loadPDFHandler.ashx", //or your url

data: {
  'FileName': "Bid" + record + ".pdf"
},
success: function (data) {
// $("#target embed").attr("src", "http://www.oldsite.com/bids/bid" + record + ".pdf");
//  alert(data);
  $("#target embed").body.update(display.data);

},
error: function (data) {
  alert('Bid PDF not found.');
},
});
```

the AJAX call is

```
  var fileName = context.Request["FileName"];

  var storageConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageConnectionString"];
  var blobContainerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageContainerName"];

  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

  CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

  CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);

  CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

  blockBlob2.FetchAttributes();
  long fileByteLength = blockBlob2.Properties.Length;
  Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[fileByteLength];
  blockBlob2.DownloadToByteArray(myByteArray, 0);


  context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myByteArray.Length.ToString());
  context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
  context.Response.BinaryWrite(myByteArray);
  context.Response.End();
```

and this is where i am failing....
I am able to see the PDF document byte array in the alert...

How do i populate the EMBED with the results of the AJAX call?

I am assuming this line

```
$("#target embed").body.update(display.data);
```

is where i need to perform the actions, but i am lost on how to actually get it done.

Answer (score -1):

Solved -

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#target embed").attr("src", "handlers/loadPDFHandler.ashx?fileName=Bid" + record + ".pdf");
// alert(data);
// $("#target embed").body.update(display.data);
```